# Convert []string to char * const []

Tags: c, go, cgo

I'm using CGO and here is the C function:

```
int init(int argc,char * const argv[]){
 //some code
}
```

I should to send the commandilne args from go to c,here is the golang code:

```
func main(){
    args := os.Args
    arg_C := convertCSliceToCharArray(args)
    C.init(C.int(len(args)),argC)
}


func convertCSliceToCharArray(slice []string)[]*C.char {
    slice_C := make([]*C.char,len(slice))
    for i,s := range slice{
        char_c := C.CString(s)
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(&char_c))
        slice_C[i] = char_c
    }
    return slice_C

}
```

Run go build and i got this error `cannot use _cgol(variable of type []*_Ctyre_char) as type **_Ctype_char in argument to _Cfunc_init`.

So in CGO,the type of `char * const[]` is `**_Ctype_char`,how can I convert []string to it?

Comment: I guess you need `&arg_C[0]` instead of `argC` in the call to `C.init`.

Comment: Despite what your function says, you don't have a "CharArray", you have a slice of C.char pointers.

Comment: So you mean The C paramter `char * const argv[]` needs the first element' pointers of the array in fact?

Comment: Yes, in C `char *argv[]` as an argument to a function is the same as `char **argv` -- ie a pointer to the first element of the char* array. I'm ignoring consts, but I don't think they matter here.

Comment: I think you are right,  can you give a formal answer here if you don't mind

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the right solution of this question is:

```
func main(){
    args := os.Args
    arg_C := convertCSliceToCharArray(args)
    //use the first element's pointers of the array
    C.init(C.int(len(args)),&arg_C[0])
}


func convertCSliceToCharArray(slice []string)[]*C.char {
    slice_C := make([]*C.char,len(slice))
    for i,s := range slice{
        char_c := C.CString(s)
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(&char_c))
        slice_C[i] = char_c
    }
    return slice_C

}
```

In C char *argv[] as an argument to a function is the same as char **argv -- ie a pointer to the first element of the char* array.

Thanks for Paul Hankin